How to make promise wait in Dynamics CRM while retrieving user details from Xrm.WebApi.online.retrieveRecord?
I am working on a Dynamics 365 project where I need to compare the logged-in user's Azure AD ID with a value from a form field and display an icon based on the comparison result. My code attempts to perform this comparison but is not working as expected.
I am implementing this code in Dataverse view which has 2 columns like below



I suspect the issue is related to handling asynchronous operations.Code is added as Event Handler where 'compareUser' function is the starting function.
Here is my code:

function compareUser(executionContext) {
    // Get Current Logged in user ID which is used to retrieve AAD id
    var globalContext = Xrm.Utility.getGlobalContext();
    var contextVal = globalContext.userSettings;
    var loggedinUserId = contextVal.userId.replace("{", "").replace("}", "");

    // Get value from field
    var fieldValID = JSON.parse(executionContext).suyog_userlist_Value.id.guid;

    // Pass both ids for comparison in function and return 0 or 1
    var finalOutput = fetchAndCompareUserIds(loggedinUserId, fieldValID);

    // Act based on returned value
    switch (finalOutput) {
        case 1:
            console.log("User matched");
            return ["suyog_testgreenicon", "Green"]; // User matched
        case 0:
            console.log("User doesn't match");
            return ["suyog_testredicon", "Red"]; // User did not match
    }
}

async function fetchAndCompareUserIds(loggedinUserId, fieldValID) {
    try {
        const result = await Xrm.WebApi.online.retrieveRecord("systemuser", loggedinUserId, "?$select=azureactivedirectoryobjectid");
        var fetched_aad_id = result["azureactivedirectoryobjectid"];

        console.log("Comparing " + fieldValID + " with " + fetched_aad_id);

        if (fieldValID == fetched_aad_id) {
            console.log("Match Found");
            return 1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.message);
    }
}


Also, in console, when I debug, it says promise pending, unsure about this.



Thanks in Advance

My expected output should be like below if User 5 is current logged in user



You just forgot to put an await there: it should be var finalOutput = await fetchAndCompareUserIds(loggedinUserId, fieldValID); and the function compareUser should be declared with async.

Thanks @trincot, that worked perfectly.

Alright. Posted as an answer.

The call to fetchAndCompareUserIds(loggedinUserId, fieldValID) returns a promise, which is why you see in the console "Promise { pending }".
As you need the actual value that will become available asynchronously, you should wait for the promise to fulfill. You can do that with await, but then your function needs to be declared as async:
async function compareUser(executionContext) {
    // ...
    var finalOutput = await fetchAndCompareUserIds(loggedinUserId, fieldValID);
    // ...
}

